# Faster Way to parse data and populate array?

Tags: android, html, regex, parsing

My code i use to parse HTMl is this below, and the 2nd code is how i call on it to populate an array for a simplelist.

The problem i have is it take upwards of 5 or 6 seconds to download, parse and display the data, which is far too long.

What is a way to speed up the process so its as close so instant as possible

Also, just so its clear i hard coded the url into the 2nd bit of code, once done, that will be passed in, depending on waht route, direction and stop you use.

```
public ArrayList<String> getStops(String URL) {
    ArrayList<String> BusStop = new ArrayList<String>();
    String HTML = DownloadText(URL);
    String temp = null;
    String temp2[] = new String[40];
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<a class=\"ada\".*</a>", Pattern.DOTALL);

    Matcher m = p.matcher(HTML);
    while (m.find()) {
        temp = m.group();
        temp2 = temp.split("<br></td>");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < temp2.length; i++) {
        temp = temp2[i];
        temp = temp.replaceAll("<a class=\"ada\" title=\"", "");
        temp = temp.replaceAll("\".*\"", "");
        temp = temp.replaceAll("\n", "");
        temp = temp.replaceAll("\t", "");
        temp = temp.replaceAll(",</a>", "");
        temp = temp.replaceAll("</tr>.*>", "");
        temp = temp.replaceAll("<td.*>", "");
        temp = temp.replaceAll(">.*", "");
        BusStop.add(temp);
    }

    return BusStop;
}
```

..

```
TransitXMLExtractor extractor;
static String baseURL5 = "http://www.ltconline.ca/webwatch/ada.aspx?r=1&d=2";

/** Populates string array with bus routes */
public String[] busStopArray() {
    extractor = new TransitXMLExtractor();
    String[] busStopArray = new String[31];

    for (int n = 0; n < busStopArray.length; n++) {
        busStopArray[n] = extractor.getStops(baseURL5).get(n);
    }
    return busStopArray;

}
```

Comment: At first I would try to find the most time consuming step. It can simply be a networking step and in this case you can hardly speed that up.

Comment: Another idea - if server is under your control switch to return data in JSON or XML (versus current HTML), then on device side it would be possible to parse the data faster.

Comment: If you plan to write a transit application, I really suggest you to contact the iRail team: http://project.irail.be/ they have a lot of tools to scrape data from transit companies, servers, and as they are NPO, everything is opensource!

Comment: So... did the updated answer work for you?

Comment: yes it did, i commented, on the lower part, it wont work when i edited it for the bus routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you could speed things up by pulling the exact text you want with the regular expression and reducing the parsing loop.

```
public ArrayList<String> getStops(String URL) {
    ArrayList<String> BusStop = new ArrayList<String>();
    String HTML = DownloadText(URL);
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<a class=\"ada\" title=\"([\\w\\s]+)\"");

    Matcher m = p.matcher(HTML);
    while (m.find()) {
        BusStop.add(m.group(1));
    }

    return BusStop;
}
```

Also, the calling bit could just be:

```
public String[] busStopArray() {
    extractor = new TransitXMLExtractor();

    return extractor.getStops(baseURL5).toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

The way I have it now, it should pull the text in the title attribute from each link of class 'ada'.

EDIT: To be clear, it should actually pull the the `<a class="ada" title="(whatever)"`, one at a time with the `group(1)` getting the `(whatever)` text for you.

EDIT 2: I updated the examples to match what I found to be working code. Also, here is the entire Activity I used to test with:

```
package com.kiswa.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String stop : busStopArray()) {
            sb.append(stop);
        }
        Log.d("STRING_TEST", sb.toString());

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public String DownloadText() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
        Log.d("STRING_TEST", "In DownloadText");
        URL url = new URL("http://www.ltconline.ca/webwatch/ada.aspx?r=1&d=2");
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
            for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
                builder.append(line.trim());
            }
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) try { reader.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getStops() {
        Log.d("STRING_TEST", "In getStops");
        ArrayList<String> BusStop = new ArrayList<String>();
        String HTML = "";
        try {
            HTML = DownloadText();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<a class=\"ada\" title=\"([\\w\\s]+)\"");

        Matcher m = p.matcher(HTML);
        while (m.find()) {
            BusStop.add(m.group(1));
        }

        return BusStop;
    }

    public String[] busStopArray() {
        Log.d("STRING_TEST", "In busStopArray");
        return getStops().toArray(new String[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the calling bit, you suggested but its not working. As well as the regex is wrong, it needs some tweeking, ill see if i can get my head around it.

Comment: I updated the answer with a tested working setup. The regex needed more escaping and the `toArray` call needed to be typed to `String[]`

Comment: By the way, the total run time for my example Activity is ~0.5 seconds.

Comment: Would you mind if i emailed you with some questions and help, Im a university student but Id be willing to pay for your time.

Comment: No need; you have StackOverflow! Ask away and I and others will be glad to help you free of charge.

Comment: Im trying to rewrite your parsing code to work for bus routes and I cant quite figure it out. 
The last part is also, to have when you click route 6-Richmond, it adds 06 to http://....ca/webwatch/ada.aspx?r= so it gives teh correct directions, and once you click north/south, it will add the correct extention(i have this part 80% working, i tried to use .concat but would get errors if pressing back for a new route.

Then the 2nd thing i need to do, is find how to parse out the correct stop extentions which are in the HTML as well. 
I'll try and edit your code, any help would be great

Comment: When ever i try to apply the same code, but for the bus routes or times, i get a empty list no matter how i try and edit, i read up on the Pattern api and stuff, and tried messing around with it, with no luck.

Comment: Have you checked out the pages? If I go to http://www.ltconline.ca/webwatch/ada.aspx?r=1&d=2 I get an error page now.

Comment: This happens every so often, not quite sure why, The other one is never down
http://www.ltconline.ca/webwatch/prediction.aspx?mode=a

I just never found out how to parse that information, or make a compiled string to request it.

Comment: I think the problem with the buses, is the &nbsp; before the table?

Comment: It's more likely to be that the RegEx isn't including numbers in its pattern. Regular expressions are a complicated beast. It may be better to find a way to access the data they're pulling from (if that's even possible).